# Replace column in one csv file from other csv file

Tags: unix, join, sed, awk

I have one csv file with below data. (, seperated)

```
C1,C2,C3,C4
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

Now I have other mapping csv file as below

```
D1,D2
1,X
5,Y
```

Here I want to find mapping in second csv file and update its value in first csv file.

Expected Output (If I want to update C3 in first csv file against two records in second mapping file)

```
C1,C2,C3,C4
1,2,X,4
5,6,Y,8
```

Comment: and http://whatHaveYouTried.com ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '1d;s%^%/^%;s%,%/s/^([^,]+,[^,]+,)[^,]+/\\1%;s%$%/%' file2 | sed -rf- file1
```

The first part transforms the second file into a sed script that can be applied to file1.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^([^,]*,)(.*)|/^\1/s/[^,]+/\2/3|' file2 | sed -rf - file1
```

Comment: Can someone please explain, I'm not able to understand what it's done. Want to replicate this for one of my cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk mapping data
```

Contents of `script.awk`:
    BEGIN {
        FS=OFS=","
    }

```
NR==1 {
    next
}

FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}

FNR>1 {
    $3 = a[$1]
}1
```

Results:

```
C1,C2,C3,C4
1,2,X,4
5,6,Y,8
```

Alternatively, here's the one liner:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { next } FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next } FNR>1 { $3 = a[$1] }1' OFS="," mapping data
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas to replace PATID values by UUID values

```
-- a.csv
PATID, ADMIT_DATE, ENC_TYPE
pat_1,2011-01-01, AV
pat_2,2012-01-01, IP
pat_3,2013-01-01, EI


-- b.csv
PATID,UUID
pat_1, uuid_xyz
pat_2, uuid_123
pat_3, uuid_abc
```

-- replace.py

```
import pandas as pd

source_file = 'a.csv'
linkage_file = 'b.csv'
out_file = 'c.csv'


def get_linked_frame(source_file, linkage_file):
    df_source = pd.read_csv(source_file, sep=',',
                            dtype=object,
                            skipinitialspace=True,
                            )
    df_linkage = pd.read_csv(linkage_file, sep=',',
                             dtype=object,
                             skipinitialspace=True,
                             )
    df = pd.merge(df_source, df_linkage, on='PATID')
    print("Source frame: \n{}".format(df_source))
    df['PATID'] = df['UUID']
    df.drop('UUID', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df


df = get_linked_frame(source_file, linkage_file)
df.to_csv(out_file, sep='\t', index=False)
print("Output frame: \n{}".format(df))

-- c.csv
PATID   ADMIT_DATE  ENC_TYPE
uuid_xyz    2011-01-01  AV
uuid_123    2012-01-01  IP
uuid_abc    2013-01-01  EI
```